# How to adjust the "+" signs in an open list? (CSS)

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to localize a theme of a website so it would be from right to left (instead of left to right:  RTL instead of LTR).

One thing I am finding it hard to do is resolving the way a list opens up to the left instead of to the right.  Here is an example of a web page with such a problem:

http://pancher.org/alerts

Could someone please advise me on how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `expandable-hitarea` class is set to `float: left`. You can change it to `float: right` and adjust a little bit of  CSS and it would work like you intended.

Comment: Thanks Uzair.  This is what I've tried doing, and the "little bit of css" is where I got stuck...

Answer (score 0):

You can either write a separate `RTL.css` and include it if the language gets switched to a rtl one. Alternative you could also write it in CSS directly:

```
<html lang="he" dir="rtl">
  ...
</html>
```

and then:

```css
html[dir='rtl'] <element> { /* styles */ }
/* or */
html[lang='he'] <element> { /* styles */ }
```

And of course you need a mirrored image-sprite to make it work.